# Unit tests work in Eclipse, not in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

We have four unit tests that work when run individually, but two fail when run together.

To make a long story short, we could get them to work in Eclipse, but not in Visual Studio Code.

First off, these are being run in Windows using Visual Studio Code with the Java Extension Pack, Debugger for Java, Java Test Runner and some other extensions. We're using JUnit 4.

Here is the problem. Two of the tests need a system variable set in order to work. In a unit test setup method we do it as such:

```
System.setProperty( "instanceType" , "BG" );
```

And like I said, that work when the two unit tests in question are run individually. When run with the other unit tests, they fail. The code that looks for that system variable throws a null pointer exception says the `instanceType` system variable is `null`.

In Eclipse, we used the Run Configurations | Arguments tab to set the system variable in the VM arguments list, thus:

```
-DinstanceType="BG"
```

With that change to the Run Configuration, all the unit tests pass.

So we wanted to get it working in Visual Studio Code. We created a test configuration in the `settings.json`:

```
{
   "java.test.config":
   [
      {
         "name": "eventsConfiguration",
         "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
         "env": { "instanceType": "BG" },
      }
   ]
}
```

But the two unit tests fail as before. Is this the right way to set the system variable?

But what really bugs us is that the code, as is, should work. It irks us that they fail when the whole suite of tests are run. The two working tests don’t use that system variable at all, so it’s not like they’re setting it to something different (and it’s a null pointer exception, so that also rules out that possibility).

So does anyone see an error in our test config or, better yet, know how to get the setProperty() call to work as it should, like it does when the tests are run individually?

Comment: Maybe change your question to "Why doesn't `setProperty()` work in my test"? And include a minimal example and other env specs.

Comment: I'll give my 2 cents: usually "system properties" are mistaken for "environment variables" (reasonably, given that both are mappings `string` -> `string`, both external to the java program). So maybe when you use `"java.test.config": [{..."env": {...},}]` you are actually configuring the test environment variables. If you want this specific mapping (instanceType -> BG) to be visible as a "system property" you'll have to configure it elsewhere (maybe `"vmArgs": "-DinstanceType=BG"`). I didn't try it though, and that's why I'm not posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added the `setProperty()` call to the other unit tests *that absolutely do not need it* and now they all pass.

So adding this:

```
System.setProperty( "instanceType" , "BG" );
```

In the passing unit tests, made the failing unit tests pass.

Hope this helps someone else someday!